# Array of Type Parameter

Tags: java, type-erasure

I am reading oracle's https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#vulnerabilities

Where its mentioned that

> In the method ArrayBuilder.addToList, the compiler translates the
>   varargs formal parameter T... elements to the formal parameter T[]
>   elements, an array. However, because of type erasure, the compiler
>   converts the varargs formal parameter to Object[] elements.
>   Consequently, there is a possibility of heap pollution.

I tried something with the following method signature;

```
static <T> void varargsOfTypeParameter(T... varargs) {  // compile warning as expected

}
```

whereas

```
static <T> void arrayOfTypeParameter(T[] array) {  // no compile warning

}
```

In both the cases, after type erasure both `T...` and `T[]` becomes `Object[]` and so there is Potential heap pollution in both cases. But, there is compiler warning only in the 1st case, whereas no warning in the latter case.

Why is this so? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Whereas... What? It's unclear what distinction you are asking about.

Comment: I just did the change

Comment: the difference is that you are explicitly passing an array in the second case, so the compiler is not having to "guess" the type of array to create, as it does in the first case.

Comment: @AndyTurner there is a small moment here that makes me always scratch my head: *However, because of type erasure, the compiler converts the varargs formal parameter to Object[] elements*, if we decompile the class with `javap`, type parameters are *there* in the declaration. Or easier `public static void fun(List<Integer> list) {
    }` will compile to `public static void fun(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>);` I just don't know why all tutorials keep saying that